# EXTJs Uncaught TypeError: this.getForm is not a function

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I wrote some code (see below) for a login page I am receiving the following
error in the Console

> Uncaught TypeError: this.getForm is not a function.

Any Help on how to resolve this...

Below part shows the code:

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Login',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        title:'Logless',
        height:200,
        width:300,
        padding:'10 0 10 10',
        closable:false,
        items:[{
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel:'EmpUID'
        },{
            xtype:'textfield',
            inputType:'password',
            fieldLabel:'Password'
        },{
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Log In',
            handler:this.Login,
            scope:this
        }],

    }).show();

},
Login:function(){
          //Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
          this.getForm().submit({
              url:'http://localhost:8085/Soumya/getFilm.action',
              success:function(form,action){
                  Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
              },
              failure:function(form,action){
                  Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
              },
          })
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error message is pretty explanatory: there's no function called `getForm` on the `this` object.

The `this` object is the application object (because that's the object in scope when the window was created, so the handler that's set up uses that). And Ext.Application objects don't have a function called `getForm`

Nor is there any form in the window - you've created a bunch of fields, and a button, but they aren't part of a form.

So there's all sorts of reasons why the code above won't work.

Fortunately, there is a [Sample Login Page in the Sencha documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/guides/tutorials/login_app.html) - I suggest you examine that.